# Using javascript to detect the domains of other tabs?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to detect what other domains a user has open with Javascript?

I'm not looking to modify anything in those tabs or have any access to the content from them.  I also don't need to know the exact URL, just the domain name each tab is accessing.

I've seen questions here about accessing other tabs via Javascript, but most are wanting to access or modify the data from those tabs - which isn't what I'm wanting to do.

Comment: Unless your javascript runs in a browser extension, I am really happy to report it's not and should not be possible.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Might be a case where a different approach is more suitable, and as @AndreaOlivato has said, safer too.

Comment: Boy that would be a crazy security/privacy violation, don't you think?  If some webpage could find out which banking website (domain) I use?

Comment: As mentioned, [browser extensions can do this](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/) (linked example is for Chrome, other browsers have similar APIs).

Comment: The only thing I can think of is the [`window.opener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener?retiredLocale=it) which gives you basically complete access on the contents of the tab that opened your site, but nothing else (also that's why all your external urls should have [`rel="noopener"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types/noopener) since the opener can be used to perform reverse tabnagging attacks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For privacy reasons, you could only do that in a browser extension, and only if the extension has been given the `tabs` permission.

[See here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/) for more information about the `chrome.tabs` API.

```
async function getInactiveTabs() {
    return await chrome.tabs.query({ active: false, currentWindow: true });
}
```